# How to use the file that is decrypted in "before_install" inside script tag. - Travis

Tags: java, encryption, yaml, travis-ci

I have an encrypted file which was encrypted using travis encrypt and the relevant decrypt function in before_install.

Now I want to use the decrypted file in the script tag. I tried to access but it will always fail saying an error. No file exists.

Is there any way to know or solve this issue because right now I am clueless. like if the error is no file exists its probably that I am searching in a wrong folder but how do I confirm that.

Comment: The decrypted file does not exist on the git repository, so it would be cleaned up before deployment unless you set `skip_cleanup: true`. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment#Uploading-Files-and-skip_cleanup

Comment: No I wanted in the same build. it worked now. Its just that I was checking in the wrong path. The issue is solved. sorry for the trouble